# Custom font not working in lollipop

Tags: android, custom-font

Is there any way to use geomanist(custom) font in android lollipop.

But it works in all other version.

Here is my code

In **MyApplication class**

```
    FontsOverride.setDefaultFont(this, "DEFAULT", "geomanist-lightnew.ttf");
    FontsOverride.setDefaultFont(this, "MONOSPACE", "geomanist-lightnew.ttf");
    FontsOverride.setDefaultFont(this, "SERIF", "geomanist-lightnew.ttf");
    FontsOverride.setDefaultFont(this, "SANS_SERIF", "geomanist-lightnew.ttf");
```

---

```
public final class FontsOverride {

public static void setDefaultFont(Context context,
                                  String staticTypefaceFieldName, String fontAssetName) {
    final Typeface regular = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),
            fontAssetName);
    replaceFont(staticTypefaceFieldName, regular);
}

protected static void replaceFont(String staticTypefaceFieldName,
                                  final Typeface newTypeface) {
    try {
        final Field staticField = Typeface.class
                .getDeclaredField(staticTypefaceFieldName);
        staticField.setAccessible(true);
        staticField.set(null, newTypeface);
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }



}




}
```

Thanks

Comment: Read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33923803/how-to-set-custom-font-for-a-whole-application-in-android

Answer (score 4):

I use this [Library](https://github.com/balrampandey19/FontOnText/blob/master/README.md) and it works superbly on all devices

Step:-

1) Add this line in your gradle `compile 'com.github.balrampandey19:FontOnText:0.0.1'`

2) Add your font in asset folder like this

[image]

3) Then replace your view in xml with

```
<com.balram.library.FotTextView
                    android:id="@+id/vno_tv"
                    .
                    .
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    app:font="regular.ttf" />
```

this line is important to set custom font you want `app:font="regular.ttf"`

You can do same for `Buttons` `Edittext`

**OR**

If you want to use same "Font" through whole application you can follow this [Guide here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42218846/4762767)

Comment: i need to change geomanist font for whole app. Not for particular text view. Anyway thanks for your response. @Akshay Katariya

Comment: I think this might be more helpful then https://stackoverflow.com/a/42218846/4762767

Comment: (stackoverflow.com/a/42218846/4762767) very useful link . Its working fine. Thank you @ AkshayKatariya

Answer (score 1):

1. The root cause of the problem is badly written font files, so it
   makes sense that the solution is to re-encode the offending font. You can use a online converting tool such as
   http://www.freefontconverter.com/.
2. Another Alternative is using a library for custom fonts like https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy

> ```
> dependencies {
>             compile 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.2.0'
>         }
> ```