# Change textview properties programatically from a fragment class

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I am relatively new to Android Studio and I am starting to explore more the Android Navigation Drawer activities. I have been trying to change the font type of a textview from a fragment class and I just can't. I have tried many different solutions available here and none of them worked. In the picture, you can see my latest attempt.

[In this image you can see the last code I tried to change the font from the fragment class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nSkIc.png)

Comment: show you project structure?

Comment: Is your fonts folder inside your assets folder?

Comment: Try out the same thing in onViewCreated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use this [Library](https://github.com/balrampandey19/FontOnText/blob/master/README.md) and it works superb on all devices

Step:-

1) Add this line in your gradle `compile 'com.github.balrampandey19:FontOnText:0.0.1'`

If this lines are missing add it in your gradle:-

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}
```

2) Add your font in asset folder like this

[image]

3) Then replace your view in xml with

```
<com.balram.library.FotTextView
                    android:id="@+id/vno_tv"
                    .
                    .
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    app:font="regular.ttf" />
```

this line is important to set custom font you want `app:font="regular.ttf"`

You can do same for `Buttons` `Edittext`

**OR**

If you want to use same "Font" through whole application you can follow this [Guide here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42218846/4762767)

Comment: Whenever I try to add that line to the gradle, I receive the following error message:

Error:(31, 13) Failed to resolve: com.github.balrampandey19:FontOnText:0.0.1

Comment: I have edited my answer, i think you are missing some lines in gradle add them from new answer.

Comment: if your problem is solved you can vote up for my answer, as it will help others :-)

Comment: I tried with your new alterations... I didn't work either

Comment: My mistake... I was adding the line in the wrong place. It worked. I marked it as the right answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Create one Class and name it whatever you want, that class will extend TextView, and that class will load the font. And further you can use that font in your xml itself. 
Like this:

```
public class CustomEditTextGEFlowBook extends android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText {

    public CustomEditTextGEFlowBook(Context context) {
        super(context);if(!isInEditMode())
        setFont(context);
    }

    public CustomEditTextGEFlowBook(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);if(!isInEditMode())
        setFont(context);
    }

    public CustomEditTextGEFlowBook(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);if(!isInEditMode())
        setFont(context);
    }

    private void setFont(Context context) {
        Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(),
                "GOTHAM-BOOK.OTF");
        setTypeface(font);
    }
}
```

Now from your xml, use your TextView or EditText like this.
.

```
<com.packageName.CustomEditTextGEFlowBook
    android:id="@+id/radioOthers"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@null"
    android:hint="Mention the Issue"
    android:maxLength="50" />
```

Comment: I tried to use this class structure to create a custom TextView, but the program crashes whenever I use it in the XML file

Comment: can you show me the log. What error are you getting.

Answer (score 0):

Verify whether font relative path is properly mentioned or not.

Comment: I can say it is properly mentioned for sure because it works just fine in the main activity

Answer (score 0):

I just checked your code, It looks okay to me. One change though, change your code from

```
return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
```

to

```
return rootView;
```

Also make sure you have provided the correct Font name

Comment: Tried to change that, but It does not solve the problem either.