# how can i change typeface for the entire strings.xml values

Tags: java, android

I am working on this project that someone else did. None of the strings are hardcoded, everythign is in a jumble of fragments and activities and its in about 10 different languages.

I'm in charge of the UI design so I need to change the fonts of the app and I want to know if there is a way to change it so that all the stuff in strings.xml get changed.

Comment: `strings.xml` has nothing to do with fonts. `strings.xml` holds strings. Fonts are applied in your UI.

Comment: ok then can i change the entire project font to a custom font without going to each individual view, making an object of it in the java code and then applying the font?

Comment: In the short term, look into libraries like [Calligraphy](https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy). In the long term, you may be able to use the new font resource support that is native to Android 8.0 and is available for some older devices via `appcompat-v7:26.0.1` and higher.

Comment: Look at this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/33923946