# How can I set text to a button in Android i.e Greek font? ex: ή έ ΰ

Tags: android, unicode, android-button

I was trying to set Greek text to my Android Button view programatically but for Button views only it is not setting. It is taking a similar kind of English font.

But the same Greek text is setting to TextViews, the problem only with the Buttons.

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnSubmitMobileNo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Υποβολή"
     />
```

Comment: What are you trying ? i mean post your code that you are using to set greek font.

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: button.setText("Υποβολή")

Answer (score 0):

I use this [Library](https://github.com/balrampandey19/FontOnText/blob/master/README.md) and it works superb on all devices

Step:-

1) Add this line in your gradle `compile 'com.github.balrampandey19:FontOnText:0.0.1'`

2) Add your font in asset folder like this

[image]

3) Then replace your view in xml with

```
<com.balram.library.FotTextView
                    android:id="@+id/vno_tv"
                    .
                    .
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    app:font="regular.ttf" />
```

this line is important to set custom font you want `app:font="regular.ttf"`

You can do same for `Buttons` `Edittext`

**OR**

If you want to use same "Font" through whole application you can follow this [Guide here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42218846/4762767)