# Having a issue on applying custom font in android app

Tags: android, fonts

I want to set a custom font in my app and done that by 
[Is it possible to set a custom font for entire of application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2711858/is-it-possible-to-set-a-custom-font-for-entire-of-application/16883281#16883281)
and i have done it but the problem is when i apply **AppTheme_1** it changes font for android version greater than or equal to lollipop and when i apply **AppTheme_2**
then it changes fonts for only android version less than lollipop. But I want to change the font for all android versions.

```
 <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
</style>

 <style name="AppTheme_1" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->

    <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/CustomTextAppearance</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>

</style>

<style name="CustomTextAppearance">
    <item name="android:typeface">serif</item>
</style>



</style>
<style name="AppTheme_2" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="android:typeface">serif</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>

</style>
```

Comment: you can refer to this link. https://stackoverflow.com/a/41790689/4571931. It works for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can achieve to set a single font to entire application using **Calligraphy lib**

Here is the library link: [Calligraphy](https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy)

Now add `compile 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.3.0'` in your build.gradle

Now create an application class like follows:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

private static MyApplication sInstance;

public static MyApplication getInstance() {
    return sInstance;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    sInstance = this;

    CalligraphyConfig.initDefault(new CalligraphyConfig.Builder()
            .setDefaultFontPath("fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf")
            .setFontAttrId(R.attr.fontPath)
            .build());
}}
```

Now you need to call this application class in manifest file like follows in application tag

```
 android:name=".MyApplication"
```

By doing this entire app have set one font. You can go through the library for better understanding.

Comment: Can this method be used for external fonts (For eg-  assests/fonts/chalk.ttf )?

Comment: @viditBabele you can use external fonts too.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

MyApplication.java (This is Application class)

```
//Typeface
    public static Typeface poppinsSemiBold;
    public static Typeface helveticaNeueMedium;
    public static Typeface poppinsRegular;

 /**
     * Preload typefaces.
     */
    private void preloadTypefaces() {
        poppinsSemiBold = Typefaces.get(getApplicationContext(), Typefaces.FONT_POPPINS_SEMI_BOLD);
        helveticaNeueMedium = Typefaces.get(getApplicationContext(), Typefaces.FONT_HELVETICANEUE_MEDIUM);
        poppinsRegular = Typefaces.get(getApplicationContext(), Typefaces.FONT_POPPINS_REGULAR);
    }
```

call this preloadTypefaces() in onCreate() of same class MyApplication.java

Typefaces.java

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.util.Log;

import java.util.Hashtable;

public class Typefaces {
    private static final String TAG = Typefaces.class.getSimpleName();
    public static final String FONT_POPPINS_SEMI_BOLD = "fonts/Poppins_SemiBold.ttf";
    public static final String FONT_HELVETICANEUE_MEDIUM = "fonts/HelveticaNeue_Medium.otf";
    public static final String FONT_POPPINS_REGULAR = "fonts/Poppins_Regular.ttf";

    private static final Hashtable<String, Typeface> cache = new Hashtable<String, Typeface>();

    public static Typeface get(Context c, String assetPath) {
        synchronized (cache) {
            if (!cache.containsKey(assetPath)) {
                try {
                    Typeface t = Typeface.createFromAsset(c.getAssets(), assetPath);
                    cache.put(assetPath, t);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Could not get typeface '" + assetPath
                            + "' because " + e.getMessage());
                    return null;
                }
            }
            return cache.get(assetPath);
        }
    }
}
```

Make sure your .ttf or .otf file is in assets/fonts/HelveticaNeue_Medium.otf added like that

res/values/attrs.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="CustomFontTextView">
        <attr name="fontStyle" format="enum">
            <enum name="poppinsSemiBold" value="1" />
            <enum name="helveticaNeueMedium" value="2" />
            <enum name="poppinsRegular" value="3" />
        </attr>
    </declare-styleable>

    <declare-styleable name="TextViewPlus">
        <attr name="customFont" format="string" />
    </declare-styleable>

</resources>
```

Custom Font class
TextViewPlus.java

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.offerbuk.R;
import com.offerbuk.app.MyApplication;


public class TextViewPlus extends TextView {
    private static final String TAG = "TextViewPlus";
    private int fontStyle;
    private TypedArray a = null;

    public TextViewPlus(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(null, 0);
    }

    public TextViewPlus(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(attrs, 0);
    }

    public TextViewPlus(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init(attrs, defStyle);
    }

    private void init(AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        try {
            this.a = getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.CustomFontTextView, defStyle, 0);
            this.fontStyle = a.getInteger(R.styleable.CustomFontTextView_fontStyle, 0);
        } finally {
            if (this.a != null)
                this.a.recycle();
        }

        if (!isInEditMode()) {
            switch (fontStyle) {
                case 1:
                    setTypeface(MyApplication.poppinsSemiBold);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    setTypeface(MyApplication.helveticaNeueMedium);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    setTypeface(MyApplication.poppinsRegular);
                    break;
                default:
                    setTypeface(MyApplication.poppinsRegular);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Use this in Your layout file

```
               <TextViewPlus
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    card_view:fontStyle="poppinsRegular" />
```