# Adding a font to Android Studio project causing build to fail

Tags: java, android, gradle, fonts, build.gradle

I've been trying to add a font to my Android Studio project but I'm not able to succeed.

Even the error which is being shown is not making any sense to me. The build is getting failed only because I'm adding a new font to my project.

I'm trying to add this font to res -> font directory.

I'm attaching two images one showing build succeeded without font in the font directory and the other showing build failed with font in the font directory.

The error remains as a big mystery to me. I'm getting ArrayIndexOutOfBounds exception! I still don't know from where I'm getting that error.

This is the first image showing successful build without font.

[image: Image without error]

This is the second image showing unsuccessful build with font added.

[image: Image with error]

Please give me some hint so that I could rectify my mistake. Thanks

This is the complete error log

```
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:100)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:60)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:97)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:87)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:248)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:241)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:230)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:123)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:104)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:626)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:581)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
    at com.android.utils.PositionXmlParser.getXmlString(PositionXmlParser.java:295)
    at com.android.utils.PositionXmlParser.getXmlString(PositionXmlParser.java:206)
    at com.android.utils.PositionXmlParser.parse(PositionXmlParser.java:139)
    at com.android.utils.PositionXmlParser.parse(PositionXmlParser.java:103)
    at com.android.utils.PositionXmlParser.parse(PositionXmlParser.java:112)
    at com.android.ide.common.res2.ValueResourceParser2.parseDocument(ValueResourceParser2.java:213)
    at com.android.ide.common.res2.ValueResourceParser2.parseFile(ValueResourceParser2.java:92)
    at com.android.ide.common.res2.ResourceSet.createResourceFile(ResourceSet.java:472)
    at com.android.ide.common.res2.ResourceSet.parseFolder(ResourceSet.java:423)
    at com.android.ide.common.res2.ResourceSet.readSourceFolder(ResourceSet.java:232)
    at com.android.ide.common.res2.DataSet.loadFromFiles(DataSet.java:248)
    at com.android.ide.common.res2.ResourceSet.loadFromFiles(ResourceSet.java:53)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.MergeResources.doFullTaskAction(MergeResources.java:136)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.IncrementalTask.taskAction(IncrementalTask.java:88)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor519.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskAction.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:121)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:92)
    ... 32 more
```

This is the build image
[image: Build failed image]

Comment: Can we see some more of the error log?

Comment: Yeah sure just give me a second

Comment: @John I've updated the question

Comment: I don't recall ever using TTF myself. While its helpful that _you_ can recreate the error perhaps you could provide a https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_Working_Example?

Answer (score 1):

Probably because you dont put the font in the right folder ?

Try to follow this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/33923946/7947225

> Put font file under assets/fonts/your_font_file.ttf

Comment: Actually I had several apps having font in that folder. That's what I'm thinking!! Any ways I would try that too and let you know. Now I've just restarted my android studio

Answer (score 1):

Whether ttf > 3MB

If it is recommended to change to a smaller < 3MB