# fonts not changing for textviews inside recyclerview items only for whole app

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, fonts, androidx

my problem is that any text views inside any items of all recyclerview don't take its font from XML, just shows the original font of the android

only items of all recycler views have this issue, other text views work fine

I have a lot of recycler view around 23 rv and there is more so it's not a good thing to change every text font programmatically 
I tried many things with no luck here 
any help?

this is an example: 
Adaptor view

```
import android.content.Context
import android.util.Log

import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.ImageView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.ecom.R
import com.ecom.data.model.FabricProduct
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.item_fabric_product.view.*


class CollectionAdaptor(var mList: List<FabricProduct>, var context: Context, val listener: (FabricProduct) -> Unit
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<CollectionViewHolder>() {

    fun updateList(newitems: List<FabricProduct>) {
        mList = newitems
        notifyDataSetChanged()
   }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): CollectionViewHolder {return CollectionViewHolder( LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_fabric_product,parent,false))
}

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CollectionViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(mList[position], listener)

    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return mList.size
    }}

class CollectionViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
    fun bind(item: FabricProduct, listener: (FabricProduct) -> Unit) = with(itemView) {
        itemView.text_subcategorie_slogan.text = item.slogan
        itemView.text_subcategorie_title.text = item.title
        setOnClickListener { listener(item) }
    }}
```

### recyclerview setup

```
mFabricProductlist = FakeData.getFabricCollection()

            rootView.rv_collection_subcategory.layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(activity!!.applicationContext, 2)

            mCollectionAdaptor =
                CollectionAdaptor(mFabricProductlist as List<FabricProduct>, activity!!.applicationContext) { //get the selected item here}

     rootView.rv_collection_subcategory.adapter = mCollectionAdaptor
```

### inside a fragment_collection.xml

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rv_collection_subcategory"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
```

## item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="220dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"

    >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_subcategorie_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_bold"
            android:shadowColor="#000"
            android:shadowDy="1"
            android:shadowRadius="1"
            android:text="000"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_subcategorie_slogan"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat"
            android:shadowColor="#000"
            android:shadowDy="1"
            android:shadowRadius="2"
            android:text="000"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="12sp" />


    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

## build.gradle

```
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-alpha3'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0-alpha03'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso- 
    core:3.2.0-alpha03'
    //Navigation
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
```

Comment: remove `android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_bold"` from your xml file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set custom font for a whole application in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33923803/how-to-set-custom-font-for-a-whole-application-in-android)

Comment: You are not using the `xml` for item that you have posted... **Your viewholder has got 3 textViews while your xml contains only 2**

Comment: @SantanuSur sorry I fixed it here thanks

Comment: @ManojPerumarath 
thanks, I tried this before, anyway I have 3 fonts not only one, so it will be the same issue
the problem is if I attached a font for specific textview inside an item of recyclerview  , it didn't change any thing just the original font.
you get me?

Answer (score 1):

use AppCompatTextView instead of TextView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="220dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"

    >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/text_subcategorie_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_bold"
            android:shadowColor="#000"
            android:shadowDy="1"
            android:shadowRadius="1"
            android:text="000"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/text_subcategorie_slogan"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:fontFamily="@font/montserrat"
            android:shadowColor="#000"
            android:shadowDy="1"
            android:shadowRadius="2"
            android:text="000"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="12sp" />


    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

it's working now, the problem was

```
mCollectionAdaptor =
                CollectionAdaptor(mFabricProductlist as List<FabricProduct>, activity!!.applicationContext) { //get the selected item here}
```

### I passed applicationContext of the activity so the solution just passes the activity

```
 mCollectionAdaptor =
                    CollectionAdaptor(mFabricProductlist as List<FabricProduct>, activity!!) { //get the selected item here}
```

thanks

Comment: I know this is an older comment, but I suggest not using !! in production code...