# Multiple font family for multiple locale - android studio (java)

Tags: java, xml, android-studio, locale, font-family

Currently I am developing a android app which supports two locale
Default    : en (English)
additional : ta (Tamil)

---

I want to set two different font-family for two different locale 
***English - signika font family
Tamil   - kavivanar font family***

---

I had tried many ways by creating locale files on fonts (Eg. font-ta). But went in vein. Please somebody help me.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J16YQ.jpg)

---

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="34dp"
    android:text="@string/body"
    android:textColor="@color/cyan1"
    android:textSize="15dp" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[How to set custom font for a whole application in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33923803/how-to-set-custom-font-for-a-whole-application-in-android)

It's an old answer, but i think you could do something similar, you could check the location and pass the different font to the `overrideFont()` method.