# How to change the font size and font family in my whole app?

Tags: java, android, fonts

so I've been working on a project for a client and I'm new to Android development, so maybe it's an easy question.

The client wants to have several options in his app settings, and he wants to change those options via a SwitchView. The options are:

- increase the font size 40% in the whole app
- change the font family to a dyslexic font (in the whole app)

I've searched all over the internet and haven't found a way to do this during runtime. So far I've made a dyslexic font family which I included in a theme in *styles.xml*. If there really isn't an easy way to do this, is there maybe a way to show an alert dialog or something like that where the user confirms the change and then the app restarts with the applied changes.

If you ask me the font size setting doesn't make any sense because the size is dependable on the Accessibility system setting, so if some's got the biggest font setting why would  he need to make it even bigger since it's only logical that the setting he's got set in his system suits him enough.

Comment: My 2 cents: You could save a boolean (say: isBigger) in your preferences. When you read it back, have a global variable which is normally set to 1.0 and set it to 1.4 (40% bigger) if the boolean is true. Then use it as a multiplier for your font size.

Comment: Check this link.
I hope you will get your answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33923803/how-to-set-custom-font-for-a-whole-application-in-android

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you change the font in the whole of the app use this library:
[Calligraphy](https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy)

and for text size, you can create a **customTextView** class and **extend** it from **TextView** and add your custom method to change textSize or fontFamily, and finally use this class instance TextView.