# Default font family not changing in android app

Tags: java, android, xml, fonts

[image: App Screenshot]

I am tried to change my font on entire app with `Style.xml` and it should change font everywhere on my app but i am getting same old font everywhere, only i see changes on dialog title not other places. Check the screenshot of app only no.2 screen dialog has changes. Can you please help me out. I am not able to get what wrong i am doing here.

Style.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
        <item name="colorSurface">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/primary_text</item>
        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/secondary_text</item>
        <item name="android:divider">@color/divider</item>
        <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
        <item name="fontFamily">@font/myfont</item>
        <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/font_elaxer</item>
        <item name="selectableItemBackground">?android:selectableItemBackground</item>
        <item name="android:colorControlHighlight" tools:targetApi="lollipop">@color/ripplecolor</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus" tools:targetApi="kitkat">true</item>
        <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/custom_hint_color</item>


        <!-- enable window content transitions -->
        <item name="android:windowActivityTransitions" tools:targetApi="lollipop">true</item>

        <!-- specify enter and exit transitions -->
        <item name="android:windowEnterTransition" tools:targetApi="lollipop">@transition/explode</item>
        <item name="android:windowExitTransition" tools:targetApi="lollipop">@transition/explode</item>

    <!--<item name="android:windowEnterTransition" tools:targetApi="lollipop">@android:transition/slide_right</item>
        <item name="android:windowExitTransition" tools:targetApi="lollipop">@android:transition/slide_left</item>-->

        <!-- specify shared element transitions -->
        <item name="android:windowSharedElementEnterTransition" tools:targetApi="lollipop">@transition/change_image_transform</item>
        <item name="android:windowSharedElementExitTransition" tools:targetApi="lollipop"> @transition/change_image_transform</item>



    </style>
```

myfont.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<font-family xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <font
        app:fontStyle="normal"
        app:fontWeight="400"
        app:font="@font/dancing_r" />
    <font
        app:fontStyle="italic"
        app:fontWeight="400"
        app:font="@font/dancing_b" />
    <font
        android:fontStyle="normal"
        android:fontWeight="400"
        android:font="@font/dancing_r" />
    <font
        android:fontStyle="italic"
        android:fontWeight="400"
        android:font="@font/dancing_b" />
</font-family>
```

Comment: look out this,  https://stackoverflow.com/a/33923946/12709358

Comment: @Ajithkumarmuthukumaran if you notice i already have default implementation from official documentation. The solutions mention in link your shared is library and myapplication hack which is not a perfect solution.